# How to make image cover responsive in mobile device by css code

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive-images

We have a problem with the website preview on mobile/tablet.
Regarding the Mobile version, home page of the website isn’t responsive completely and the main cover (https://mineteams.com) doesn’t show all the pictures on it while in the demo version of it this problem doesn’t exist.

Now you are requested to help us solve this problem.

**PHP Code:**

```
<div class="pth-hero__scene pth-parallax" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) rotate(0.0001deg); transform-style: preserve-3d; backface-visibility: hidden; pointer-events: none;">
```

**CSS Code :**

```
      div.pth-hero__scene.pth-parallax {
        background:  no-repeat fixed center center / cover rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        height: 40%;
        left: 0;
        position: cover;
        top: 10%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to make sure that all pictures of your background image are shown on smaller screens as well, you need to set your background-size to:

```
.pth-hero__background-inner {
 background-size: contain !important;
}
```

In regards to your homepage not being completely responsive: please be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your helps, now the problem with images responsive showing on mobile devices is solved.but we have a problem with the website preview on mobile/tablet yet.
Regarding the Mobile version, home page of the website isn’t responsive completely and the main cover (https://mineteams.com)doesn’t show all the text on it while in the demo version of it this problem doesn’t exist.and the problem is just text responsive showing now.
Now you are requested to help us solve this problem.
Thanks